# Proving or disproving a set of total functions is countable

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, proof-techniques, counting

> Let S be the set of total functions from $N \rightarrow M$, such that for each $f \in S$, there is $i > 1$ such that for
>   all $j < i$, $f(i)$ and $f(j)$ are not equivalent Turing machines. Prove or disprove that S is countable

I don't think this is actually countable, but I'm having a hard tie proving this using diagonilzation. Can anyone give me pointers / hint? Preferably explained at a lower level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $M_1,M_2$ be an arbitrary pair of inequivalent Turing machines. Your set $S$ contains all functions satisfying $f(1) = M_1$ and $f(2) = M_2$.

Comment: Not sure I understand here. Would you mind expanding a bit? I'm only in an introductory course, so I'm not sure whether I'm reading this correctly or not.... You're saying since we can let i = 2, and j = 1 and j < i by the question's statement the set contians all of these and so it is countable? Just no infinitely countable?

Comment: It's just a hint. You'll have to work out the rest.

Comment: I understand I'll have to work out the rest..... I'm trying to make sure I understand you rhint. The hint does little good if I don't understand / misinterpret your answer.

Comment: The only way to learn is to solve exercises. I've given you a start.

Comment: Okay. Here's my attempt. Wondering if I've done anything glaringly wrong. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be an arbitrary pair of inequivalent Turing achines. Note that by definiton of S we have that $S$ contains all functions satisfying $f(1) = M_1 $ and $f(2) = M_2$. Suppose $S$ is countable. Then there exists an exhaustive list of these functions: $f_0, f_1, .... $. Consider $g: N \rightarrow M$ defined by $g(x)=f_x((x+1)mod 2 + 1) $. (I made f(1) -> f(2) and f(2) -> f(1)). By definition we have that $g(x) \ne f_x(x)$ for all $x$ and so $S$ cannot be countable.

Comment: Great! You've got it. You can also say that $S$ includes all functions $f$ such that $f(1) = M_1$, $f(2) = M_2$, and $f(n) \in \{M_1,M_2\}$ for all $n \geq 3$. This is isomorphic to infinite binary sequences, which are known to be uncountable.